# Fundamental their of cyclic groups and U(10).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Theorm (paraphrased from Gallian's 'Contemporary Abstract Algebra', 4ed): If the order of a group generated by a is n, we have that for each divisor k of n there is exactly one subgroup of order k, namely < a^n/k >.

Question: Take the group <3> = (U(10), *mod10) = {1,3,7,9}  which has order 4.  The subgroup of size 4 is itself, of size 2 is <3^4/2>={1,9}, and of size 1 <3^4/1>={1}, but what about <7> = <3^3>?  Aren't there two subgroups of size 4, and one isn't even given by the formula?

Comment: The entire group has order $4$, as you point out...it hasn't got a different subgroup of order $4$.  What you are noticing is that the group has more than $1$ generator, but the theorem you quote says nothing about the number of generators.

Comment: @lulu Ah, thanks! I see the confusion I was making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $7 \equiv -3\pmod{10}$, so $7^2\equiv(-3)^2\equiv 9\equiv -1\pmod{10}$. Then $7$ also has order $4$ in $U(10)$, but the group generated by $7$ isn't different: it's still just $U(10)$. This phenomenon comes from the fact that a cyclic group will have more than one generator in general. In this case, $7$ is a generator as well as $3$, so you can apply the formulas with $7$ in place of $3$. You will obtain different generators in general, but they will generate the same subgroup (as there is indeed only one subgroup of order $k$ for each $k$ dividing $n$).